# Communicating between Lua and NodeJS using WebSockets not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, lua

I am making a control panel for my Minecraft mining turtle and I need to communicate between the two using websockets. I have troubleshooted the Lua side of things and that works as intended when I connected it to a echo server.

Code here:

```
local ws,err = http.websocket("wss://localhost:5757")

if ws then
    ws.send("Hello")
    print(ws.receive())
    ws.close()
end
```

However, I can not get the NodeJS side to work. I have tried different ports, I've tried opening ports.

Code here:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 5757 });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log('received: %s', message);
  });

  ws.send('testing 123');
});
```

I can't figure out where I have gone wrong. All help is appreciated.

EDIT: Thought I'd add that it's not giving errors either, that I am using the ws npm package and running the latest LTS node version.

EDIT 2: I tried this code example here

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const ws = new WebSocket('wss://echo.websocket.org/');

ws.on('open', function open() {
  ws.send('testing 123');
});

ws.on('message', function incoming(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

And it worked and replied with 'testing 123' so it seems that the web socket doesn't want to run on local host.

Comment: You’re using wss instead of ws... this means the web socket would fail on nodejs’s side as it cannot encrypt the message (similar to https). A proper url would be `ws://localhost:port`